Is there any command to turn off the real time protection on windows security?
I am trying to disable the "Real-Time Protection" feature in Windows Defender programmatically for testing purposes. However, I’ve encountered issues with all the methods I’ve tried which was given on the stackoverflow.
What I’ve Tried:
Command Prompt:
netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off

Result: This command seems to control the firewall, not real-time protection.
PowerShell Command:
powershell
Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true

Result: It seems to be run but on the windows security it does not turn off the real time protection
My Environment:

Windows 10/11
Administrative privileges are available.
No third-party antivirus is installed.
PowerShell version: (please let me know if this matters and how to check it).


Have you tried the things in the first answer here? You must start powershell in administrator mode and paste all the commands. Works for me.

You will have to turn off Tamper protection first

fyi this is off-topic here, as the [tag:windows] tag description explains: "GENERAL WINDOWS SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC." [su] is the site for general computing questions.

@DavidMakogon, since the question is specifically about how to script the task, it is programming-related.
